# How to hash string in java script?

Tags: javascript

I need to hash a password in java script.i google it for days and find some articles but i could not understand the point.
can any one help me up on this please??

Comment: Search for a SHA256 implementation for Javascript, and call the SHA256() function on your password.

Comment: Do you really need hashing? Wouldn't you be better of by encrypting your connection with SSL/https?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have a native function to hash strings.

http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html is a function someone has written to produce an md5.

Copy the code from here http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html into your javascript, then run `hex_md5(s)` where `s` is the text you want hashed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remakes of PHP's md5() and sha1() functions in javascript.

- sha1 - http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1:512
- md5 - http://phpjs.org/functions/md5:469

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the safest way to do this is to send the password using ajax to a php or aspx-script and hashing it there. People will always, always be able to read your js-code, hence, they can crack the hashing algorithm, or simply mimic it.